# Can not find Picasa Web Album, under Google App admin panel/google app/Other Google Services

Tags: google-workspace, picasa, google-plus

We got a Google App account that we use with our domaine name. We use the core service apps (gmail, calendar, drive, etc.). Now we are looking into going into Google+. To be able active Google+ for my users, I need to activate Picasa Web Album first.

But I can't find it anywhere in my admin panel. It's suppose to be under Google Apps/Add Services/Other Services, but it's not. The only thing I see there is "Google App Engine" and "Google Apps Marketplace".

Is it because I don't have Google Apps for business account?

Thanks.

Comment: I also have this problem - although I can see "Calendar", "Contacts", "Drive", etc under the "Google Apps" page, when I click the "Add services" button I'm taken to a page that only has the ID field for Google App Engine, and a link to the Google Apps Marketplace.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to enable additional services, given the lack of options shown for you (and me) on the Google Apps/Add Services/Other Services page.

In my case, it is the actual Google+ service that I wish to enable.

From the Admin console, I clicked "Users". Then I clicked on the name of one of my main users to view their User Details. Then I clicked "Show More" at the bottom of the page, and one of the revealed headings is "64 More Google services enabled". I clicked this and a side-panel opens up, with a list of services.

Scrolling through that list, I noticed that Google+ was "Off". Clicking on it took me to a page with a large g+ icon and a drop-down underneath that allows me to select "ON for everyone". Clicking this brings up a confirmation dialog that warns that it may take 24 hours to take effect, so I have yet to confirm that this works completely.

Hopefully this might help with the Picasa service, which I see is also in that list of "more services", albeit already ON for me.